# Change the colour of all particles on screen

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to make it so when the user clicks a button, the colour of all particles on screen change to a certain colour. Is there a way to change the colour of all particles on screen coming from the same particle emitter at runtime? I know there is the main module's startColor property, but that only changes the particle colour for new particles, not ones currently on screen. Currently I've tried messing around with the colorOverLifetime module, but I just get these weird blend between the original colour and the new one.

Comment: Presumably you tried setting the start colour to white, so that you don't get a "weird blend" when combining it with the colour over lifetime gradient?

Comment: No I did not! That solution worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to DMGregory, I learned the answer was to just set the starting color to white, while setting the color over lifetime module's color to whatever color desired.